# Operate a Desktop program with sofware

Tags: vbscript, desktop

I would like to operate a (Windows) Desktop program. Because i use this on a daily basis to do some simple operaition. (Open a file PDF file, render it and save it in another folder).

I would like to do this by using somekind of service or script. I have been looking into VBscript to do this but i'm getting stuck at some operations that are normally done by users.

For example if i would like to open a file a user would go to File > Open and select the desired file. Off course the script could go to file and open but how do you select a certain file (the newest file in a certain folder).

Is it possible to have a piece of code to do these operations within a Desktop program or am i trying to do something impossible or maybe i'm using the wrong tools. Below a piece off testcode for what i'm trying to accomplish.

```
    Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    WshShell.Run """C:\Program Files (x86)\programname.exe"""
    wsh.sleep 1000 ' wait 1 second
    WshShell.AppActivate """Program name"""

    WshShell.SendKeys "^o" ' Open file
```

Any help is greatly appreaciated.

Comment: Dear newbee, please consider accepting an answer (THE answer :-), or comment on it so one knows what you are waiting for. Otherwise, this questions keeps popping up as open, which is very annoying if one is looking for questions worth a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You are trying to control an application through its GUI, but it is not designed for that.**

Having said that, I estimate this will be a nightmare if you do not use tools (or an app :-) ) explicitely created for that purpose, a la test robots like HP QTP or automation tools like Autoit http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit.

For example, if your application occasionally flushes the keyboard buffer, you might need to wait for some GUI event before sending the keystroke. **This kind of synchronization is not accomplishable using vbscript only.**